# Why qemu can't detect a WHPX (Hyper-V) accelerator?

Tags: windows-10, virtualization, qemu

I've been messing around with qemu on Windows 10. I found HAXM as a slow accelerator (for me has the same performance as TCG) and I want a better experience. I found that qemu supports WHPX, using `-M accel=whpx`. I enabled Windows Hypervisor Platform and everything from the Hyper-V category in Windows Features and then I restarted the machine. I tried to run qemu using whpx but I get this error:

```
qemu-system-x86_64: WHPX: No accelerator found, hr=00000000
qemu-system-x86_64: failed to initialize whpx: No space left on device
```

Here is the relevant part of systeminfo:

```
    OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
    OS Version:                10.0.19043 N/A Build 19043
    OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
    OS Configuration:          Standalone Workstation
    OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
    System Manufacturer:       Micro-Star International Co., Ltd.
    System Model:              MS-7C89
    System Type:               x64-based PC
    Processor(s):              1 Processor(s) Installed.
                               [01]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 165 Stepping 3 GenuineIntel ~3600 Mhz
    BIOS Version:              American Megatrends Inc. 1.50, 21/07/2020
    Windows Directory:         C:\Windows
    System Directory:          C:\Windows\system32
    Boot Device:               \Device\HarddiskVolume2
    System Locale:             en-us;English (United States)
    Input Locale:              en-us;English (United States)
    Total Physical Memory:     16,320 MB
    Hotfix(s):                 5 Hotfix(s) Installed.
                               [01]: KB5007289
                               [02]: KB5000736
                               [03]: KB5008212
                               [04]: KB5007273
                               [05]: KB5005699
    Network Card(s):           7 NIC(s) Installed.
    Hyper-V Requirements:      VM Monitor Mode Extensions: Yes
                               Virtualization Enabled In Firmware: Yes
                               Second Level Address Translation: Yes
                               Data Execution Prevention Available: Yes
```

Do I need to rebuild qemu by myself?
NOTE: I used this setup file: https://qemu.weilnetz.de/w64/qemu-w64-setup-20211215.exe

Comment: I would use the most recent release from December 2021 before I tried anything. [This](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/qemu-devel/2018-04/msg04898.html) error does not seem new by the way.

Comment: Yeah I saw that thread, but it didn't help, also the version I linked is the lastest version provided weilnetz

Comment: It tells me that the Hyper-V accelerator might not actually be working.  [This](https://gitlab.com/qemu-project/qemu/-/issues/430) seems more relevant.

Comment: Is there any utility that can actually test if Hyper-V is actually working?

Comment: Wait.. Hyper-V manager is a thing

Comment: I created really quick a vm using that manager but it seems that the hypervisor is not running, as seen here https://imgur.com/a/mNerMVW

Comment: Hyper-V != Windows Hypervisor Platform.  While you could try enabling Hyper-V I very much doubt it will work since Windows Hypervisor Platform is what actually provides the ability to use the accelerator. A better test would be WSL2, if that works, then you don't have conflicting software installed. By the way HAXM works then Hyper-V is already enabled.  Your performance issues might be just connected to the CPU itself.  Your specifications are less than clear what processor you have.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the hypervisor's startup is disabled. It may be installed but it needs to be started at boot. Use this command in an admin command prompt and then reboot. This will force Windows to start the hypervisor at each boot.

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype on
```

Comment: All research indicates that the only requirement is Windows Hypervisor Platform not Hyper-V itself.

Comment: @Ramhound: Yes, but ever since the introduction of WHP, the _actual hypervisor_ is now part of the Hypervisor Platform, not part of Hyper-V – the Platform couldn't do its job otherwise. The bcdedit option is not specific to Hyper-V.

Comment: @user1686 - In my experience it is. It's certainly not required for WSL2. I have only ever seen `hypervisorlaunchtype` connected to enabling Hyper-V.  In fact, until recently, it had to be off for VMWare and VirtualBox to work.

Comment: @Ramhound: Well, exactly, it had to be off for VirtualBox to work because VBox brings *its own* hypervisor (which conflicts with the Windows Hypervisor) and until recently didn't support WHP... People only associate the option with Hyper-V because it was pretty much the only user of the hypervisor before Microsoft made WHP available to the public, but now the "Hyper-V" feature is a consumer of WHP.

Comment: Due to changes to VirtualBox it’s not technically required for VirtualBox and VMWare.  I would like this answer to explore the concept of verifying, Hypervisorlaunchtype is even enabled, before blindly issuing a command